# Por que o alarme não abre a Activity?

Tags: android, android-alarmmanager

Eu tenho no meu código um alarme que é suposto tocar quando chegar as horas 22:48 mas nada acontece agora pergunto me se as horas que o calendar usa são as horas de sistema ? se sim o que eu estou a fazer mal para o meu alarme não aparecer ?

Chamo a função para inserir um novo alarm ao clicar em uma lista :

```
boolean res = MyUtility.addFavorite(HorariosActivity.this, horarioitem,
                                    HorariosActivity.this.getApplicationContext());
```

a função retorna um valor boleano caso seja `true` adiciona aos favoritos.

**Na minha Utility class tenho o código que supostamente faria tocar o alarm:**

```
 public static boolean addFavorite(Activity activity, String favItem , Context context) {


        String favList = getStringFromPreferences(activity, null, EVENTOS);


           AlarmManager alarmMgr;
           PendingIntent alarmIntent;

            alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);


            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 22);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 55);


            alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 10 , alarmIntent);



    }
```

Eu enquanto teste a aplicação deixo-a sempre aberta porque sei que caso de restart pelo que sei os alerts são perdidos , ainda assim não funciona o meu alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código está a definir um *Intent* para uma *Activity*:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
```

no entanto está a criar um *PendingIntent* para um *BroadcastReceiver*:

```
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
```

Se o pretendido é o *Alarm* lançar a `MainActivity` altere a linha anterior para:

```
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
```

Nota: Os alarmes não são perdidos se fechar a aplicação apenas serão perdidos se desligar o dispositivo.

Comment: Já modifiquei o código e continuo sem receber o alarme esperado alguma sugestão?

Comment: O que quer dizer com "continuo sem receber o alarme esperado"? O que espera que aconteça com o "disparar" do alarme?

Comment: Foi um mal entendido da minha parte. Obrigado pela ajuda está a funcionar o alarme agora tenho outro problema com o disparar de uma notificação mas vou abrir outra pergunta para isso.